# Using prism 5.0 to develop a wpf add-on

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

My app is an IDE add-on, so the project is a wpf user control. I want to use Prism to refector it now. When I debug the app, it threw such an exception in `InitializeComponent();` of the `MainView`'s constructor:

```
"ServiceLocationProvider must be set."
```

I also found a similar thread here: [Strange exception in Prism application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169996/strange-exception-in-prism-application)
 but there's no solution.

This is my bootstrapper class:

```
 class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainView>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        ModuleCatalog catalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleInit));
    }
}
```

This is my ModuleInit class:

```
 public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    IRegionManager regionManager;
    IUnityContainer container;

    public ModuleInit(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.container.RegisterType<ViewModelA>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(Models.RegionNames.ARegion, () => this.container.Resolve<ViewModelA>());
    }
}
```

Because this is a user control project, so there's no App.xaml and App.xaml.cs file. I can bootstrapper's Run method in MainView's constructor:

```
 public MainView()
 {
        InitializeComponent();      
        Bootstrapper strapper = new Bootstrapper();
        strapper.Run();
 }
```

But the exception is thrown in the first line of the constructor. Anyone can help?

Furthermore, is there a way to use Region without modularity? My app only contains one project, it needn't modularity. If yes, where can I register the views, services and viewmodels?

Comment: Why are you using the service locator to find an instance of the shell?  Why not have unity resolve on it?

Comment: @GayotFow using this piece of code has the same issue:protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.TryResolve<MainView>();
        }

Comment: That's the question to solve.  If unity cannot do it, then something's seriously wrong.  Using the service manager because the container throws an exception is just hiding the problem.

Comment: I see the problem now.  You are trying to run a boot strapper from within the constructor.  Initialize component is being called twice because main view has never been constructed.

Comment: @GayotFow Where should I call the run method? There's no App.xaml and App.xaml.cs file in my project

Comment: It is intended to be decoupled.  You'll need to find a separate entry point.  There is probably a quick fix where you override the bootstrapper constructor, but I don't know if prism has any value in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, for example in your bootstrapper before init code, you have to define your IoC container.
This is how it's done in ViewModelLocator by default:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```